# How to trigger an event onMousewheel?

Tags: javascript, three.js, mousewheel

I am developing a WebGL application. For example, I have a sphere object that uses orbit controls for Zoom in/out.

Now I want to setup an event for the mousewheel. When zooming on my current WebGL block corresponding map location it can be zoomed in/out (used inline-block) for maps and WebGL. But the problem is that first of all my event is being triggered when I use the mousewheel. I also want to know whether my event logic is correct or not.

```
root.addEventListener('mousewheel', mousewheel, false); 

function mousewheel(event) {
    var mX = (event.wheeldetailX/width)* 2 - 1;
    var mY = (event.wheeldetailY/height)* 2 + 1;

    var WebGLZoom = new THREE.Vector3(mX, mY, 1);
    var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();

    raycaster.setFromCamera(WebGLZoom, camera);
    WebGLZoom.sub(camera.position);

    var mapzoom = map.getZoom();

    if (WebGLZoom.z <= 5 && WebGLZoom.z > 2) {          
        map.setZoom(17);
    } else if (WebGLZoom.z <= 2 && WebGLZoom.z > 0.0) {     
        map.setZoom(19);
    } else {                
        map.setZoom(14);
    }                               
}
```

Comment: The standard event is `wheel`.

Comment: Google will help you: [*How to Use the Mouse Wheel Event in HTML5 Pages*](http://www.sitepoint.com/html5-javascript-mouse-wheel/)? :p

Comment: do you mean instead of mousewheel can i use wheel...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `wheel` event like so.

```
document.addEventListener('wheel', function(event){
    console.log(event.deltaY);
}, false);
```

This will result in a console log every time your mousewheel scrolls over the document. The `deltaX` and `deltaY` properties of the `MouseWheel` event are especially useful to figure out exactly how much the user scrolled and in which direction.

Comment: Thank you #GMchris...now its working i have checked.

Answer (score 0):

The event to use is [wheel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/wheel). You can find a working example [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onwheel_addeventlistener).